# C-shell Script: Disk checking

Tags: shell, unix, csh

i am new in shell script. i have given a task to make a C-shell script. I have list of ip address and device name respectively. For example;

```
cal 1 : 100.21.25.10
cal 2 : 100.21.25.11
cal 3 : 100.21.25.12
cal 4 : 100.21.25.14
and so on..
```

Right now, i have this.

```
#! /bin/csh -f

set device = (cal1 cal2 cal3)
set ipaddress = (100.21.25.10 100.21.25.11 100.21.25.12)
set highspace=60

foreach data($ipaddress)

set rspace = `rsh $data df -k | grep /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0 | awk '{print $5}'| cut -c1-2`

if (${rspace} >= ${highspace}) then
echo "Please Housekeep $device "
endif

end
```

output:

```
100.21.25.10
61
Please Housekeep cal1 cal2 cal3
```

why its only iterate one time? And how to have ip address will link to device name?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran it, and it iterates properly, going through each of the IPs in the list.

My guess is you are only seeing the one line of output because `rspace` is less than 60 for the other IPs, so the `if()` clause evaluates to false, and the `echo` is not called.

To get a hostname from an IP, you can:

```
dig +short -x 173.194.33.71
```

Also, most of society has abandoned `csh`: https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+don%27t+use

This would be a better `csh` script:

```
#!/bin/csh

exec /bin/bash new-bash-version.sh
```

Comment: yeah..im not realized that..do u have idea how to link the ip and device name, So that, when rsh the ip, the message will come out Please Housekeep cal1 not Please Housekeep cal1 cal2 cal3?

Comment: if i removed the if statement, it will not compare with the set highspace=60..after being compare with set highspace=60, then if high than 60, show messge please housekeep

Comment: erm....actually i need to rsh the ip address for the cal 1-3..so..the please housekeep (device name) is link with the ip address..like if rsh 100.21.25.10, this for cal1, it will show please housekeep cal1 and if rsh 100.21.25.11(cal2), will show please housekeep cal2..